# Adding a Facebook friend using JS in a PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app with PhoneGap and one of my targets is WP so I cannot use the PhoneGap Facebook plugin.

What I want to do is to let the user add a friend from within my app.

So I did some researches and I've found this question [Can I "add friend" with Facebook's API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421200/can-i-add-friend-with-facebooks-api)

One of the answers talks about using the JS SDK but in the comments it has been said that this one is an old method (as an extra, I can't even get the JS `ReferenceError: FB is not defined`)

So I'm trying with the next reply.

This one say to look at this feature https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/ and, if I'm not wrong, this means having a link like this one

`https://m.facebook.com/dialog/friends?id=<friend id>&display=touch&app_id=<app id>&redirect_uri=<redir url>`

and, when the user clicks on it, it will show a dialog to confirm the friendship request.

Now, since the app is something local, I'm trying to use a local page as a `<redir url>` which leads me to this error:

> The redirect_uri URL must be absolute

So the question is:
how can I use this feature WITHOUT having any page on a webserver and by doing everything locally in my app?

Is it even possible or any Facebook app is forced to have some kind of server backing?

Comment: Although I have build many phonegap applications I never had need to do this, but could you check what `document.domain` returns inside phonegap (don't have time to check myself right now, nor any devices closeby).

Answer (score 1):

Go through this plugin for Facebook.I have developed an application using this plugin for Facebook.

[Facebook-plugin-For-Android](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect)

And From Here,You can browse for any plugins for any platform.

[Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)

You have to learn how to integrate plugin in PhoneGap application.Use this plugins you will get all your requirements.

Comment: Any idea on how it works? The sample page provided is stuck on the "loading" screen and it seems not to get past the `FBConnect.install()` method which seems pretty important :\