# Is it possible to make a facebookfriend by using the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a workflow go smoother.

Already tried to Google it, but I've got nothing to show for it.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: No, there is no way to add friends or even send a friend request via API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a number of ways to do that [Can I "add friend" with Facebook's API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421200/can-i-add-friend-with-facebooks-api) . But all of them are deprecated for a moment. So I believe the actual answer is no, there is no way to add a friend trough API.