# its possible add friend with command line in twitter with tha twitter api in command line?

Tags: api, twitter, command-line

I read about the facebook api but not has option for add friend

Is possible add friend with twitter api

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index

please help me

I refer **twitter** api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I "add friend" with Facebook's API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421200/can-i-add-friend-with-facebooks-api)

Comment: i put the TWITTER api ; i try with facebook before and not works

Comment: facebook remove  the option of add friend of the facebook api

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you trying to add a friend on Facebook using the Facebook API? or are you trying to do this on Twitter?

Comment: in twitter please sorry  for misunderstand